# AxoniQ how to configure SpringBeanParameterResolverFactory as part of MultiParameterResolverFactory for spring beans to dependecy inject

Tags: dependencies, code-injection, axon

This might be a simple one, but I have tried all the axon blogs and did not find exact configuration in how to configure the SpringBeanParameterResolverFactory as part of the delegated list of MultiParameterResolverFactory.

ExternalService.java

```
@Component
public class ExternalService {

    public void testcall(){
        System.out.println("test operation called");
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<axon.version>4.5</axon.version>

...
...

  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${axon.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Inside Aggregate class

```
  @CommandHandler
    public GiftCard(IssueCmd cmd, ExternalService externalService) {
        externalService.handle();

        logger.debug("handling {}", cmd);
        if (cmd.getAmount() <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("amount <= 0");
        }
        apply(new IssuedEvt(cmd.getId(), cmd.getAmount()));
    }
```

But at runtime, I am getting below exception

```
Caused by: org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.UnsupportedHandlerException: Unable to resolve parameter 1 (ExternalService) in handler public io.axoniq.demo.giftcard.command.GiftCard(io.axoniq.demo.giftcard.api.IssueCmd,io.axoniq.demo.giftcard.service.ExternalService).
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.AnnotatedMessageHandlingMember.<init>(AnnotatedMessageHandlingMember.java:76) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.jar:4.5]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.AnnotatedMessageHandlingMemberDefinition.lambda$createHandler$0(AnnotatedMessageHandlingMemberDefinition.java:51) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.jar:4.5]
...
...
```

Also checked the MultiparameterresolverFactory and is the list its not showing the SpringBeanParameterResolverFactory.

[image]

Request for the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `ExternalService ` a Spring `@Component`? If yes, this should work out of the box.

Comment: Apologize for few details mentioned @LucasCampos. Have added few more with the exception details getting at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you be able to elaborate on why you need to configure the ParameterResolver yourself? Normally, this isn't needed at all, especially not for the `SpringBeanParameterResolverFactory` as it will be auto-configured for you.

Simply provided the `ExternalService` in your application context, by either annotating it directly or by having a bean creation method should suffice.

---

If you do need to add additional `ParameterResolverFactory` instances, the following approaches should be sufficient to automatically attach them to the used `MultiParameterResolverFactory` without your interference:

- Adding the fully qualified class name of your `ParameterResolverFactory` to a file called `org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.ParameterResolverFactory` inside your `resources/META-INF/services` folder. Axon uses the Service Loader approach to load them, which means you can attach to this if needed.
- When in a Spring environment, you can simply annotate your custom `ParameterResolverFactory` with `@Component` and the framework will pick it up. So simply put, if you add it to your Application Context, Axon can find it.
- You can override Axon's `ParameterResolverFactory` entirely by registering it as a component to the Configuration API. To that end, you would use the `Configurer#registerComponent(Class<C>, Function<Configuration, ? extends C>)` method. Note that this **will** require you to provide the `MultiParameterResolverFactory` as apposed to the previous two options.

Comment: I do agree that I did see the mention about the `SpringBeanParameterResolverFactory` and tried the same but its not getting wired in the list of resolvers in `MultiParameterResolverFactory`, the same in show in the screenshot.

Added the codebase as whole in the repo https://github.com/mnkartik/gitfcard-demo, stripping down to required classes.

Comment: I am following the same approach by using @Component on the bean which I am injecting in the command handler, but its not getting injected and exception is returned, because SpringBeanPRF is not getting listed in the MultiPRF, as shown in the screenshot. Not sure If I am missing any configuation. Any link to the working example code would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble @Steven, its working fine, had some issue from my side.

Comment: No need to apologise Kartik, I am just happy to hear you have uncovered the problem! If any other Axon questions pop up, know you can keep using SO or the dedicated Axon Forum -> https://discuss.axoniq.io/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog](https://axoniq.io/blog-overview/set-based-validation) about set-based consistency validation and added some code samples on Github for it. One of the examples is using a ParameterResolverFactory. See https://github.com/AxonIQ/code-samples/tree/master/set-based-validation at point 3

Comment: Thank you @Yvonne, but I was looking for the `SpringBeanParameterResolverFactory`, as mention below, which what I read from blogs was, gets injected automatically in the `MultiParameterResovlerFactory`, but its not happening. Hope I am not missing any configuration. also added the same code here https://github.com/mnkartik/gitfcard-demo

Comment: @KartikNarayanaMaringanti it looks like something is wrong with the Spring setup and the components are not loaded when handling the command, if you look are the code samples you can see a repository was injected in the Account aggregate. There are no issues with that code.